# GridLayoutManager populates items vertically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want a horizontal scrollable gridview. So I'm using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. Here is my GridLayoutManager

```
GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

The problem is it populates items like this

1 3 5

2 4 6

but I want it this way

1 2 3

4 5 6

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
```

Comment: well, I had to wrap recyclerview inside HorizontalScrollView and set recycleView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false to make it work.